# Custom Domain Visualforce Pages are not working

Tags: visualforce, custom-domain

We use a custom domain, organisation.my.salesforce.com

A couple of users this morning reported on of our apps was not working. When I logged in and tested, it looks like all custom Visualforce pages served from the organisation--c.visualforce.com/ are just giving a DNS error message (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

Initially I thought this was an internal network issue, but I have tested via tethering my machine to a 4G connection, and am still getting the issue.

All of the managed packaged pages are working - for example Finacialforce, which pages have a URL format of organisation--ffc.visualforce.com are working fine.

I have raised a case with Salesforce support, and they have started 'working' on the case a few hours ago, but I've heard nothing from them, apart from an email saying this is a developer issue and we should consider purchasing a support plan.

I've checked the Setup Audit trail, and none of the other administrators have made any changes in the last 24 hours.

Am I missing something, or is this clearly a Salesforce infrastructure issue?

Comment: On which instance or domain your are...i mean na..cs..ap..?

Comment: Once you enable custom domain, Your Org's URL changes.
So if you have referenced any VF pages with their URL, it won't work.
Try changing the reference URLs.

Comment: We are on the NA8 instance. Custom domain has been enabled for two years with no problems, this morning pages just stopped resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like deeper in the Setup Audit-Trail (yes, quite a large org with a number of administrators making changes), another administrator had recently installed an un-namespaced package by mistake and reverted this by uninstalling the package.

It looks like there is an known-issue, that when this happens, Salesforce thinks 'Oh, there is no un-namespaced packages, so I no longer need that DNS entry/redirects for the un-namespaced Visualforce - organisation--c.visualforce.com'. When in truth, yes it does, as in our case we had hundreds of pages that were custom built by administrators and developers, and never deployed through packaging.

Luckily, after scouring the internet and trailblazer community, [I came across this link explaining the same issue, and steps to resolve](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iir0QAA)

What I managed to do is use a developer organisation that I utilised in the pre Trailhead scratch org days. In that org, I created a single Visualforce page, with a simple 'Hello World' message inside. I then went and created an unmanaged package, without a namespace, and added the Visualforce page to it as a package component. I then uploaded the package, to get an install link.

After a period of a few minutes whilst the package propagated between instances, I was then able to install the package in our production org.

Once installed, the DNS/redirect issue was immediately remedied, and all of our custom pages started working.

Two days after resolving the issue, Salesforce support then decided that they could fix the issue by running a script, which I then told them I had resolved the issue myself.